# Where in the Bible did Jesus revisit the demon possed man from Decapolis?

Tags: john, matthew, luke, healing

Where in the Bible did Jesus revisit the demon possed man from  Decapolis?

Comment: Why are you asking this ?

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics. A tip for the future; this is an academic site designed to answer specific biblical text questions based on grammar and context. Therefore, the questions need to address a specific biblical text so the responders have a basis on which to answer. In your case, can you amend your question to add chapter and verse references to aid the members to be able to give you a proper answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mark 5:20 mentions the Decapolis when Jesus healed the demon possessed man.

Mark 7:31 mentions at least one time afterward that Jesus visited the Decapolis, but doesn't mention the man formerly demon possessed.  Note John's statement about what was recorded in the Gospels:

> Now there are also many other things that Jesus did. Were every one of them to be written, I suppose that the world itself could not contain the books that would be written. (John 21:25, ESV)